# Excel formulas giving #VALUE! error when ported to Mac

Tags: excel, macos

I want to be able to sum up the number of cells in a range that have a non-null value in them. On a PC running XP and Excel I entered `=SUM(IF(G$19:G$1034="",0,1))` and it spit out the correct answer. Now the same spreadsheet on a Mac running Excel 2004 for Mac gives that a `#VALUE!` error. Any thoughts on why?

Comment: This is exactly a question for Joel.

Comment: He might say he didn't work on the Mac port of Excel :p

Comment: What does "same spreadsheet on a Mac" mean? Did you copy it or did you type the formulas in again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enter it as array (matrix) formula. After typing the formula don't hit enter but hit either

<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> or
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Where CMD is the apple key. I'm not sure what the keycombination is on mac. But you can check in the help file. Entering array formula

Answer (score 10):

I realize that the post was mede a long time ago, but i recently and regularly have the same problem - and I always seem to forget the solution:
Select the cell or range of cells that contains the array formula, press <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to edit the formula, and then press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>RETURN</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

It might be settings that control the separator character. That "," is the separator on one machine and something else, for example ";" is the separator character on the other.

Comment: As far as I know, the separator is locale-dependent and is used only for formula entry and display; it's not actually stored in the compiled-into-RPN formula saved in the file. In any case it's easy to determine: type in =SUM(1,2) in one cell and =SUM(1;3) in another; one will produce 3 and the other will produce an error dialogue box -- you won't get as far as #VALUE! because the formula is syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is mac-specific. I have always used

```
=COUNTA(G$19:G$1034)
```

for this purpose.