# Excel formulas giving Value Error in Mac

Tags: excel, macos, vba

To preface, I have already tried the Ctrl+U and Command+Enter as detailed here: [Excel formulas giving #VALUE! error when ported to Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022766/excel-formulas-giving-value-error-when-ported-to-mac)

Problem: Data ported from SAS stacks the two needed values into one cell. So I am using a step process to automatically split the cell and then concatenate based on desired values.

Here is the formula that works in PC, but showing a Value Error when trying to work with the spreadsheet in Mac Excel.

```
=LEFT('Data Input'!B7,FIND(CHAR(10),'Data Input'!B7)-1)
=RIGHT('Data Input'!B7,FIND(CHAR(10),'Data Input'!B7)-1)
```

Comment: If you switch `CHAR(10)` to `CHAR(13)` does it work?

Comment: Yes, that works. What did that do? And, will [CHAR(13)] work on PC?

Comment: Your issue is related to historical differences between how Windows and Mac represent line breaks. `CHAR(13)` likely won't work in Win XL  - typically that uses `CHAR(10)`  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: Try - `=LEFT('Data Input'!B7,IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(13),'Data Input'!B7),FIND(CHAR(10),'Data Input'!B7))-1)`