# Excel SUM check on duplicates

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I am working on a data sheet where I have a list containing team members and their allocated tasks each month in percent.

I want to do a check where I see if there are any duplicates and if this is true I want to check if work allocation is above 1.

If this happens I would like to somehow indicate those team members are over-allocated. I thought this could be done with color marking on the name or a cell showing names that are over-allocated.

I attached this example with 11 names where David and Martin are overallocated.

Can I do this with basic Excel statement or VBA code?

Thanks for your help.

//David
[image: Data List]

Comment: Is a duplicate any repeat of a given name in column A?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a pivottable and filter out count <2. Assume this as an allocation of over 1 in a month?

Comment: Yes. a duplicate is a name appearing more than once in column A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivottable method (Note I used some dummy actual values):

Set your data up as a table and add an end column called `NameCount`. Assuming your first column you put a header name in cell `A1` then you can put the following formula in the new column top cell e.g. 02 and it will autofill down.

```
 =COUNTIF([Name],[@Name])
```

Dummy data:

[image: Data view]

Create a pivot off the data and arrange like so:

[image: Pivot]

Filter out anything <= 1 from the NameCount.

Apply conditional formatting to the column ranges in your pivottable containing the month data:

Formula:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(C14),C14>1)
```

Make sure $ is not present as you want the formula to be applied to all cells in range.

An example range (I have kept this short) for the formula to apply to:

[image: Example conditional formatting range: You would set this for all your months]

Answer (score 2):

In your example David is over allocated by 0.1 for January...

You could have 2 formulas to get your desired result, this is an example of just 1 month, drag the second formula across for the remainder:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(A:A,$A2)>1,ROW(A:A)),ROW(1:1))),"")` - First column (this is an array formula, while still in the formula bar hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)

This will return the smallest row number for index, where the count of the result in column A is more than 1...

`=IF($P2<>"",SUMIF($A:$A,$P2,B:B)-1,"")` - Assuming P is the column with the first formula.

---

Edit:
For Apple Mac an array formula is entered like so:

(taken from [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26605282/6387479))

> Select the range, press <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and then press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>RETURN</kbd>.

---

Comment: Hmm. I could not get it to work on my Mac with the formular. Stupid mac :D

Comment: @TheDave For future reference, array formulas can be enetered for Mac following [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26605282/6387479)