# How to enter array Formula in Excel 16.27 for MAC

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having problems entering this Formula that should count all unique values in a range: `=SUM(1/COUNTIF(F15:F341,F15:F341))`

I tried several combinations to enter the Array Formula but none work.
I tried the following: cmd + return, cmd + shift + return

I also tried the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26605268/array-formula-on-excel-for-mac) Post but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

To enter an array formula on a mac in excel, all you need to do is use the "ctrl" and "shift" keys and enter.

So, hold down "ctrl" & "shift" **then** enter...

Answer (score 0):

=SUM(1/COUNTIF(F15:F341,F15:F341))

the sum function needs at least 2 numbers to work, in you formula you put just 1.
the countif already take the criteria and count if this criteria is in the range.

Try this, if it's not work tell me.

```
=1/COUNTIF(F15:F341,criteria)
```

Please, specify the criteria. You can put something like >0

```
=1/COUNTIF(F15:F341,>0)
```

Anyway. if you have questions this site maybe help
https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-countif-function